# How to change CSS of one page from another page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two web pages:

`pageone.html` and `pagetwo.html`

In **`pageone.html`**, there is a button with an id of `change-color`
When you click that button, the background color of **`pagetwo.html`** is supposed to turn green.
But that isn't happening.
Can someone help me?

```js
function changeColor() {
  //code

  var pageTwo = 'pagetwo.html';
  pageTwo.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="change-color" onclick="changeColor">Change Background Color</button>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you really mean since pagetwo.html has not been loaded when you are on pageone.html

Comment: My idea would be to set the colour value in a cookie and then read and set it on the `window` focus event

Comment: How are these two pages related? Where is pagetwo.html when pageone.html is displayed?

Comment: The cookie approach is only possible when he two pages are part of the same website.

Comment: I'm assuming they are part of the same website

Comment: Does the button also redirect to pagetwo.html? If so, maybe a simple query string will do the trick.

Comment: Too many vague points (that haven't been answered) to provide anything other than a guess.  1) are the two pages open at the same time?  or does the button redirect to the 2nd page?   2) do you have any server-side actions that you can use (eg websockets/signalr)?   3) is this for a single user or should it change if you click the button and then I open page 2? (or even change my page 2 that I already have open?)

Comment: The two pages aren't open at the same time. The button doesn't redirect to pagetwo.html

Answer (score 3):

You can try like below

In pageone.html

```
 window.localStorage.setItem("bg", "")
 function changeColor() {
         window.localStorage.setItem("bg", "green");
 }
```

In pagetwo.html

```
<script>
var bg = window.localStorage.getItem("bg");
if(typeof bg!= 'undefined' && bg != ""){
    //Set your background using bg variable
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, cookies or local storage are probably the only easy ways to achieve this. But also this only applies to the specific user and changing the background color is not visible to other users.